# PHP - How to combine a list of arrays that are at the same level

Tags: php, arrays

After flattening a multidimensional array, I have a resulting array, which running print_r() on gives me the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9999
)
Array
(
    [0] => 8888
)
Array
(
    [0] => 7777
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6666
)
```

I'm hoping to combine these arrays, so that print_r() would output it like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9999
    [1] => 8888
    [2] => 7777
    [3] => 6666
)
```

Looking through stackoverflow and other documentation, I've seen suggestions on **array_merge, array_merge_recursive, array_combine, implode, and others,** but for some reason (maybe because these arrays are all at the same level?), these suggestions haven't worked.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Here is a simplified example of how I'm getting this strange output:

```
$multi_dim_array = array(
        array("Details"=>array("Category"=>array("CategoryId" => 15, "CategoryName" => "Misc Products"), "Id" => 1, "Number" => 9999)),
        array("Details"=>array("Category"=>array("CategoryId" => 12, "CategoryName" => "Random Products"), "Id" => 2, "Number" => 8888))
    );


    function array_flatten($array) {

        $return = array();
        $nums = array();

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $return = array_merge($return, array_flatten($value));
            } else {
                $return[$key] = $value;
            }       
            
        }
        
        if(isset($return["Number"])) {      
        
            array_push($nums, $return["Number"]);
    
            // echo "<pre>";
            //   // var_dump($array);
            //   print_r($nums);
            // echo "</pre>";

            $output = array_reduce($nums, function($carry, $item) {
                $carry[] = $item;
                return $carry;
               }, []);
              
            echo "<pre>";   
                print_r($output);
            echo "</pre>";
        }   

        return $return;
    }

    $result = array_flatten($multi_dim_array);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I also tried pushing them into a new array using array_push, but this just added another level / dimension to each individual array.

Comment: Hi, just asking if my updated answer works for you?

Answer (score 1):

Initial Variable

```
$arr = [
 [ 999999 ],
 [ 888888 ],
 [ 777777 ],
 [ 666666 ]
];
```

One liner:

```
$output = array_merge(...$arr);
print_r($output);
```

With reduce

```
// This is your format
$output = array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item) {
 $carry[] = $item;
 return $carry;
}, []);

print_r($output);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 999999
    [1] => 888888
    [2] => 777777
    [3] => 666666
)
```

Comment: Welp, you beat me to it! :) nice answer.

Comment: hi Rajesh, thanks for your quick response!

Unfortunately, I tried your suggestions, and it gave me this output again:

Array
(
    [0] => 999000000
)
Array
(
    [0] => 999000003
)
Array
(
    [0] => 999000001
)
Array
(
    [0] => 100007038
)

Since these are listing, and not showing the parent array that they are nested in, just about everything I try results in either that output, or it adds another level to each individual "parentless" array.

Comment: @splace could you edit your question with little more context? From where do you get the array? Because if your array is as you claim on question than this will solve it for you.

Comment: @splace Perhaps share a minimum reproducible example of this code so that we may try this on our own? because as stated by Rajesh, if the array is as you speak, this should work.

Comment: Stranger and Rajesh thank you both, I'm working on a simplified example (the original multi-dimensional array is huge). I hope to update the question soon with it.

Comment: @Stranger and Rajesh I've posted the example in the original question, I included one of your solutions in there Rajesh, I'm still pretty new to php so I may have gotten in over my head with the recursive array flattening function.

Comment: @splace have you tried the specific `...` syntax from our answers? Meanwhile, I'll see your code.

Comment: @splace See my updated answer now, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new_array = array_merge(...$old_array);
print_r($new_array);
```

Also see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

**Edit:**

Now that I've seen the updated answer, here is my solution:

```
<?php

$nums = array(
  array(
    0 => 9999
  ),
  array(
    0 => 9999
  ),
  array(
    0 => 8888
  ),
  array(
    0 => 8888
  ),
  array(
    0 => 8888
  )
);
$output = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($nums); $i++) {
  $current_subarr = $nums[$i];
  array_push($output, $current_subarr[0]);
}

print_r($output);

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9999
    [1] => 9999
    [2] => 8888
    [3] => 8888
    [4] => 8888
)
```

Comment: thank you for continuing to suggest solutions. 

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get numbers array to show as a nested array, no matter what I try, it seems to always show as a list of arrays that are not nested after using that recursive flattening function:

array
(
   0 => 9999
),
array(
   0 => 9999
),
array(
   0 => 8888
),
array(
   0 => 8888
),
array(
   0 => 8888
)

Comment: @splace Hi, I'll give a retake exactly with your code as soon as I get free from my work.

Comment: thanks @stranger, I'll keep an eye out, no rush.

Comment: @splace No problem, right now I am into some deadlines I have to get out of the schedule, only if I could get 10 minutes to do this... anyways, I'll probably respond somewhere after 2 days if that's not too late for you...